# Spark / Scala - Compare Two Columns In a Dataframe when one is NULL

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark (Scala) to QA data movement - moving tables from one relational database to another. The QA process involves executing a full outer join between the source table, and the target table.

The source table and target tables are joined in a data frame on the key(s):

```
val joinColumns = for (i <- 0 to (sourceJoinFields.length - 1)) yield sourceDF.col(sourceJoinFields(i)) <=> targetDF.col(targetJoinFields(i))
val joinedDF = sourceDF.join(targetDF, joinColumns.reduce((_&&_)), "fullouter")
```

I'm using the following logic to find mismatches:

```
val mismatchColumns = for (i <- 0 to (sourceDF.columns.length-1)) yield (joinedDF.col(joinedDF.columns(i)) =!= joinedDF.col(joinedDF.columns(i+(sourceDF.columns.length))))
val mismatchedDF = joinedDF.filter(mismatchColumns.reduce((_||_)))
```

However if there is a key missing from one side of the full outer join:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|source_key    |source_field  |target_key    |target_field  |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|null          |null          |XXX           |XXX           |
```

will not be in the mismatchedDF data set.

So my question: is the `=!=` operator the opposite of the `<=>` operator? It does not appear to be, so is there an operator that will return FALSE for this case? I can't find much documentation on either operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The opposite of `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` (`<=>`) is `IS DISTINCT FROM` (`not(... <=> ...)`).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.not

val df = Seq(("foo", null), ("foo", "bar"), ("foo", "foo")).toDF("x", "y")
df.select(not($"x" <=> $"y"))
```

or

```
df.select(!($"x" <=> $"y"))
```

or

```
df.selectExpr("x IS DISTINCT FROM y")
```

all giving the same result:

```
+---------------+
|(NOT (x <=> y))|
+---------------+
|           true|
|           true|
|          false|
+---------------+
```

Of course if you have a disjunction of negations:

```
(NOT P) OR (NOT Q)
```

you can always use De Morgan's laws to rewrite it as a negation of concjunctions

```
NOT(P AND Q)
```

therefore:

```
not(joinColumns.foldLeft(lit(true))(_ and _))
```

should work just fine.